# performSegueWithIdentifier Firing, But Not Displaying

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue

Very sorry for adding yet another post on this, but I've read all the other solutions and nothing is working. I have a very simple scenario.

**MasterViewController** adds a bunch of custom UIButtons to a view. That displays perfectly. When my custom button is called, I then route the button back to the **MasterViewController** to transition the next **SecondViewController** to display on top of itself.

My code is something like this:

**[custom button setup func]**

```
func setup() {

    self.masterViewController = self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MasterView") as! MasterViewController
}

func clicked()
{
    self.masterViewController.transition("SecondViewSegue") // matches the segue identifier perfectly
}
```

**[MasterViewController func]**

```
func transition(segueName: String)
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier(segueName,sender: self)
    });

}
```

**What I've confirmed:**

- The custom UIButton fires
- The **performSegueWithIdentifier** is firing
- The **prepareForSegue** for the **MasterViewController** is firing
- The **viewDidLoad**() func is firing in the **SecondViewController**

**Things I've tried:**

- Reconnected the Segue
- Confirmed spelling is identical (see above performance)
- Tried with and without the dispath_async command (again, all fires)

There really isn't anymore code involved. I'm confused.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Check the source code for storyboard by right clicking MyStoryBoard->Open As->Source Code.

Search for :`trigger="accessoryAction"` 
If you find it , delete it.

Sometime ctrl+dragging adds this additional attribute causing issues with prepareForSegue.

Comment: Didn't find any, but that's a cool feature I wasn't aware of.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found my problem. I had accidentally created a new instance of the original UIViewController. So even though the functions were calling, it was not referencing the viewController on screen.